# .Net: Is there a Dictionary to efficiently store/load its contents in a file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, dictionary

In (VB).NET (4.0 framework), I'd need a `Dictionary<string, string>` that can efficiently store its contents, or better its internal representation to a file and load it later.

Ruby has such a thing in PStore, see [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/PStore.html).

The intention is to once prepare a lookup dictionary for e.g. text translations out of a database and store it in a disk file that can quickly be loaded multiple times for output generation. So this should not read the file line by line and fill the Dictionary with the key-value pairs, but instead load the file contents in one go directly into its internal state representation.

I think this should be possible, but I would also like to see your explanations if you think otherwise.

Comment: If you are asking how to serialize the dictionary to a file so that it can be read later, use  the `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` classes as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4022629/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter: This method also adds each key/value pair one-by-one. I'd prefer to read the whole internal class representation if possible.

Comment: I would use sqlite and write a wrapper `SQLiteDictionary` class which implements `IDictionary<K, V>` and takes the filename name in the constructor.

Comment: Sounds like you are working really hard to save a few milliseconds.  Are you sure you need to do this?  To be able to thunk a blob from memory to a file and back directly into your storage data structure you are going to have to code it in unmanaged C++ or do a lot of interop into custom .NET data collection objects and VB.NET lacks `unsafe` support to deals with pointers so it will not be fun.

Comment: @tcarvin: I'm evaluating possibilities, not optimising prematurely. :) So you are saying that in managed code it's not possible to save the internal "memory" state of an object?

Comment: You can pin it in a couple of ways so it won't be moved and then access the backing memory, but you need more than the backing memory of a single object, you need it of the larger container data structure.  I'd think that would be implemented by the data structure allocating its storage and that of any children in a contiguous block, and you are not going to get that behavior in .NET unless you do it yourself from scratch.

Comment: @tcarvin: Maybe you'd care to point out such a concept in an answer? This sounds like a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, I still think any benefit you get is going to be out-weighed by the effort to implement.  I recommend looking into something [BerklyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) or [HamsterDB](http://hamsterdb.com/about), both of which I googled up in a couple of minutes.

If really want to hand-implement something, I think perhaps instead of writing your own memory manager with the `Marshal` class to ensure that your data-structure are stored in a contiguous block that can marshaled quickly to and from a file backing, I would look at using a persistent [memory-mapped file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx).  Then you can use [CreateViewAccessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267546.aspx) to get a `MemoryMappedViewAccessor` instance that can be used to read and write primitive and data structures.  Combine this with any college text or open source implementation of something like a [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) or something [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) and you could get something working.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep it simple for this particular task, I would to it this way:

```
class Pair {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"asd", "zxc"},
    {"111", "zzs"}
}; // Populate your dictionary somehow
var list = dict.ToList().Select( p => new Pair() { Key = p.Key, Value = p.Value} );
//Then XML-serialize this list
```

To read it:

```
//De-XML-serialize that list
dict = list.ToDictionary( p => p.Key, p => p.Value );
```

Side advantage is that you can modify stored list with just text editor.

Comment: Well thanks, but introducing a whole database system for this task is a bit too much for my use case.

Comment: @gpinkas I didn't read your question properly, see my update.

Comment: That looks better. I still hope for a faster solution though, my intention is to improve loading speed. Maybe this is already as far as it will go using only the .NET builtin data structures.

Comment: @gpinkas improve your speed by finding bottlenecks, not by premature optimisation.

Comment: Of course, but I want to evaluate possible optimisations, also in terms of development time. If I'd have to implement this completely from scratch with uncertain outcome, it's hardly viable. But if someone has already built something similar, I would check further on this optimization.

Comment: @gpinkas it is trivial task to implement it manually in case it takes too long. Just store it in 'key=value' format and you are done. Can be implemented in 10 minutes, we already spend more time discussing it.

Comment: No, it's not, because to access items by `my_dict[key]`, you still have to feed the values into a dictionary. I think my question is clear in this aspect.