# C# How to call FieldInfo.SetValue function without manual type conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, reflection, fieldinfo

I want to save data-class instance to database and load it from database. and I want to generate sql command automatically. so, I think that I need to use dictionary< string, string> so that solve it.

refer my old question : [How to convert 2D string array to 2D [int, double, bool, ..] array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942178/how-to-convert-2d-string-array-to-2d-int-double-bool-array)

working process like these.

1. convert data-class instance to dictionary < string, string>.
2. save/load dictionary to/from txt, database, etc.
3. convert dictionary to data-class instance

I think I have solved the problem anyway. but I think converting 2D array method is still not a perfect one. I wonder, when I call FieldInfo.SetValue function, is there another way to solve type conversion without using switch/case state like my solution.

help me simplify my code.

Data class like this

```
        public class DCylinderData
    {
        public int ID;

        public int[] Solenoid = new int[2];
        public int[] UpSensor = new int[DEF_MAX_CYLINDER_SENSOR];
        public int[] DownSensor = new int[DEF_MAX_CYLINDER_SENSOR];

        public double MovingTime;

        public ECylinderType CylinderType;
        public ESolenoidType SolenoidType;

        public bool[] boolTest = new bool[3];
        public string[] nameTest = new string[2];
        public int[,] TwoDimension = new int[3,4];

        public DCylinderData()
        {
        }
    }
```

main code like this

```
            // 0. initialize
        DCylinderData cylData = new DCylinderData();
        cylData.ID = 99;
        cylData.MovingTime = 1.1;
        cylData.CylinderType = ECylinderType.UPSTREAM_DOWNSTREAM;
        cylData.Solenoid = new int[]{ 2, 3};
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)
        {
            cylData.Solenoid[i] = i + 2;
            cylData.nameTest[i] = $"NameTest_{i}";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < DEF_MAX_CYLINDER_SENSOR; i++)
        {
            cylData.UpSensor[i] = i * 1;
            cylData.DownSensor[i] = i * 4;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cylData.TwoDimension.GetLength(0) ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cylData.TwoDimension.GetLength(1) ; j++)
            {
                cylData.TwoDimension[i, j] = i * cylData.TwoDimension.GetLength(1) + j;
            }
        }
        cylData.boolTest[0] = true;
        cylData.boolTest[1] = false;
        cylData.boolTest[2] = true;

        // 1. Class -> Dictionary
        Dictionary<string, string> fieldBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        Type type = typeof(DCylinderData);
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            // 1.1 element
            if (field.FieldType.IsValueType)
            {
                fieldBook.Add(field.Name, field.GetValue(cylData).ToString());
            }
            // 1.2 array
            else if (field.FieldType.IsArray)
            {
                Array array = (Array)field.GetValue(cylData);

                // 1.2.1 1-D array
                if (array.Rank == 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        fieldBook.Add($"{field.Name}__{i}", array.GetValue(i).ToString());
                    }
                }
                // 1.2.2 2-D array
                else if (array.Rank == 2)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                        {
                            fieldBook.Add($"{field.Name}__{i}__{j}", array.GetValue(i, j).ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteLine($"Not support {field.Name}'s array {array.Rank} dimension.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                WriteLine($"Not support to handle {field.Name}'s {field.FieldType.ToString()}");
            }
        }

        // 2. print Dictionary
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in fieldBook)
        {
            WriteLine($"FieldBook {item.Key} : {item.Value}");
        }

        // 3. Dictionary -> Class
        DCylinderData copyData = new DCylinderData();
        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            // 3.1 handle element
            if (field.FieldType.IsValueType && fieldBook.ContainsKey(field.Name))
            {
                SetFieldValue(copyData, field, fieldBook[field.Name]);
            }
            // 3.2 handle array
            else if (field.FieldType.IsArray)
            {
                Array array = (Array)field.GetValue(copyData);
                string key, value;

                // 3.2.1 1-D array
                if (array.Rank == 1)
                {
                    var arr_1d = new string[array.GetLength(0)];
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        key = $"{field.Name}__{i}";
                        value = fieldBook.ContainsKey(key) ? fieldBook[key] : "";
                        arr_1d.SetValue(value, i);
                    }
                    SetFieldValue(copyData, field, arr_1d);
                }
                // 3.2.1 2-D array
                else if (array.Rank == 2)
                {
                    var arr_2d = new string[array.GetLength(0), array.GetLength(1)];
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                        {
                            key = $"{field.Name}__{i}__{j}";
                            value = fieldBook.ContainsKey(key) ? fieldBook[key] : "";
                            arr_2d.SetValue(value, i, j);
                        }
                    }
                    SetFieldValue(copyData, field, arr_2d);
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteLine($"Not support {field.Name}'s array {array.Rank} dimension.");
                }
            }
            // 3.3 not support
            else
            {
                WriteLine($"Not support to handle {field.Name}'s {field.FieldType.ToString()}");
            }
        }

        WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        ReadLine();
```

and, SetFieldValue Functions like these

```
        public static void SetFieldValue(Object target, FieldInfo fieldInfo, string value)
    {
        string fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType.Name;
        fieldType = fieldType.ToLower();

        switch (fieldType)
        {
            case "boolean":
                bool b;
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, bool.TryParse(value, out b) ? b : false);
                break;

            case "int32":
                int n;
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, int.TryParse(value, out n) ? n : 0);
                break;

            case "double":
                double d;
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, double.TryParse(value, out d) ? d : 0);
                break;

            case "string":
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, value);
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void SetFieldValue(Object target, FieldInfo fieldInfo, string[] arr)
    {
        string fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType.Name;
        fieldType = fieldType.ToLower();
        fieldType = fieldType.Replace("[]", "");

        switch (fieldType)
        {
            case "boolean":
                bool b;
                bool[] arr_b = Array.ConvertAll(arr, s => bool.TryParse(s, out b) ? b : false);
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, arr_b);
                break;

            case "int32":
                int n;
                int[] arr_n = Array.ConvertAll(arr, s => int.TryParse(s, out n) ? n : 0);
                //int[] arr_n1 = Array.ConvertAll(arr, int.Parse);
                //int[] arr_n2 = arr.Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out n) ? n : 0).ToArray();
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, arr_n);
                break;

            case "double":
                double d;
                double[] arr_d = Array.ConvertAll(arr, s => double.TryParse(s, out d) ? d : 0);
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, arr_d);
                break;

            case "string":
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, arr);
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void SetFieldValue(Object target, FieldInfo fieldInfo, string[,] arr)
    {
        string fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType.Name;
        fieldType = fieldType.ToLower();
        fieldType = fieldType.Replace("[,]", "");

        // 0. string return
        switch (fieldType)
        {
            case "string":
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, arr);
                return;
                break;
        }

        // 1. initialize
        int n;
        double d;
        bool b;

        //object[,] output = new object[arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1)];
        int[,] output_n = new int[arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1)];
        bool[,] output_b = new bool[arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1)];
        double[,] output_d = new double[arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1)];

        // 2. convert
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                switch (fieldType)
                {
                    case "boolean":
                        output_b[i, j] = bool.TryParse(arr[i, j], out b) ? b : false;
                        break;

                    case "int32":
                        output_n[i, j] = int.TryParse(arr[i, j], out n) ? n : 0;
                        break;

                    case "double":
                        output_d[i, j] = double.TryParse(arr[i, j], out d) ? d : 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        // 2. setvalue
        //fieldInfo.SetValue(target, output);
        switch (fieldType)
        {
            case "boolean":
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, output_b);
                break;

            case "int32":
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, output_n);
                break;

            case "double":
                fieldInfo.SetValue(target, output_d);
                break;
        }
    }
```

this is all part of my code.

Comment: Maybe this is a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `GetElementType`, `Array.CreateInstance`, `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter` and `dynamic`(optional). You will still need quite a bit of code to do it since you need to cater for exceptions and unknown types, and errors in the string.

To answer you question, you can do 3 things:

Replace the 3 lines starting with `string fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType.Name;` with one line: `string fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType.GetElementType().Name;`

then replace your 1D array output with:

```
dynamic output = Array.CreateInstance(fieldInfo.FieldType.GetElementType(), arr.GetLength(0));
```

And your 2D array output with:

```
dynamic output = Array.CreateInstance(fieldInfo.FieldType.GetElementType(), arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1));
```

BUT this is where it gets tricky: you will need to create a "type converter" function from the fieldInfo and use that in your for loops. but you cannot 'unbox' and object to the desired type without knowing exactly what type you are converting to. So unfortunately you will *need* case statements (or something similar). Basically the arrays are the problem, although now you only need 1 switch statement:

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(fieldInfo.FieldType.GetElementType());
for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        switch (fieldType)
        {
            case "Int32":
                output[i,j] = (int)converter.ConvertFromString(arr[i,j]);
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}

fieldInfo.SetValue(target, output);
```

---

That is so much effort for what is essentially serializing. Here is a better solution:

1. First get Json.NET from NuGet into your project
2. Replace the `// 1. Class -> Dictionary` section with `string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cylData);`
3. To get the class back: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DCylinder>(output);`

Solved in 2 lines of code :)

---

Anything else and you should post it in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks, Balah. Your help has been very helpful to me. and I will consider using Json.Net serializer.

Comment: First step is incorrect. You should download `Newtonsoft.Json`. `Json.NET` does not contain the class `JsonConvert`.